# C header to delphi

Tags: c, delphi

I have a piece of C code. I need help to translate it to Delphi code.

## 1)

```
/*
 * Color is packed into 16-bit word as follows:
 *
 *  15      8 7      0 
 *   XXggbbbb XXrrrrgg
 *
 * Note that green bits 12 and 13 are the lower bits of green component
 * and bits 0 and 1 are the higher ones.
 * 
 */
#define CLR_RED(spec)      (((spec) >> 2) & 0x0F)
#define CLR_GREEN(spec)    ((((spec) & 0x03) << 2) | ((spec & 0x3000) >> 12))
#define CLR_BLUE(spec)     (((spec) >> 8) & 0x0F)
```

## 2)

```
#define CDG_GET_SCROLL_COMMAND(scroll)    (((scroll) & 0x30) >> 4)
#define CDG_GET_SCROLL_HOFFSET(scroll)     ((scroll) & 0x07)
#define CDG_GET_SCROLL_VOFFSET(scroll)     ((scroll) & 0x0F)
```

Comment: As a side-note: The c header as a bug: `(spec & 0x3000)` should be `((spec) & 0x3000)`

Comment: For the life of me, I can't imagine why anyone would choose to use a macro for this. When you fix the bug the CodeInChaos spotted, which are so easy to make with macros, you then have the fact that `(spec)` is evaluated twice in `CLR_GREEN`. If you want to define a function, define a function!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But it's faster1!11 Compilers that can inline functions are unheard of.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this looks as a legacy of some old hardware - and thus some old compiler as well

Answer (score 11):

These are parameterized macros. Since Delphi doesn't support these, you'll need to use functions instead, which is cleaner anyways.

- `>>` is a right-shift, `shr` in Delphi
- `<<` is a left-shift, `shl` in Delphi
- `&` is "bitwise and", `and` in Delphi
  Delphi uses bitwise operators when working on integers, and logical operators when working on booleans, so there is only one operator `and` to replace both `&&` and `&`.
- `|` is "bitwise or", `or` in Delphi
- `0x` is the prefix for hex literals, `$` in Delphi

So `#define CLR_GREEN(spec)    ((((spec) & 0x03) << 2) | ((spec & 0x3000) >> 12))` becomes something like:

```
function CLR_GREEN(spec: word):byte;
begin
  result := byte(((spec and $03) shl 2) or ((spec and $3000) shr 12));
end;
```

(I don't have delphi at hand, so there might be minor bugs)

Convert the other macros in a similar manner.

Comment: @Arioch'The - is it necessary for these small integer manipulation functions? Won't the compiler do it automagically for you?

Comment: @Leonardo No it won't. And in anycase, we can't tell whether inlining is a good idea. Only author could know that.

Comment: Inlining is probably a good idea, assuming these functions will be called for each pixel in a bitmap.

Comment: @Leonardo - by default - not. And if you want to set auto-inlining, then include the proper pragma into code to override defaults.
However i don';t remember if auto-inlining works on all functions or, again, only those hinted by `inline` keyword